# LibreOffice (soffice) command line stuck when executed as a node child process

Tags: node.js, libreoffice

I am running headless, command-line libreoffice to convert documents to pdf or png. I am running. E.g.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to png --outdir /tmp /tmp/myfile.pub
```

The conversion happens successfully when I run the command on the command line directly. However, if I run it by spawning (or execing) a child process in node, it just hangs (the conversion does not happen). When I do a `ps aux`, I can see this command running.

Any idea why it may be happening?

I have already tried a number of things, including:

1. Used full path to binary
2. Ensured the file permissions are all good

Comment: same here, but using php

Comment: Please add some code (how do you spawn/execute the child process?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server restart miraculously fixed it.

Comment: Hi, have you run into the same issue since the miraculous restart?

Comment: Thanks, though I did figure out the issue yesterday: multiple soffice instances will cause this issue. XD

Answer (score 0):

As borisdiakur has already noted, it is difficult to debug this without actual code. Also, I don't have soffice installed on this machine. BUT, something like this should work, and if it doesn't it should at least give you some more insight by printing out the output of your command:

```
var spawn   = require('child_process').spawn,
    soffice = spawn('soffice', ['--headless', '--convert-to', 'output.png', '--outdir', '/tmp', '/tmp/myfile.pub' ]);

soffice.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

soffice.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

soffice.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

**Update 0:** Ok, I went ahead and tracked down the soffice executable on my hdd (apparently I did have it). The command executes just fine when given the proper path. One thing I had to do to make it happy was create the output.png file YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add an answer for the benefit of WINDOWS users trying to launch LibreOffice from an IIS application. There are several things that can cause LibreOffice to not work and/or hang. My own checklist was:

1. Give permissions on working folder to IIS AppPool/DefaultAppPool
2. Launch soffice.com NOT soffice.exe
3. On command line, explicitly set output folder
4. On command line, explicitly set a different profile folder

For the full lifesaver post, see:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/accessing-libreoffice-from-iis-10-hangs-on-bootstrap/43719/7